# 'More than one file was found with OS independent path project.properties' Error in android

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I'm getting this error after I added google translate api on my project. I am using Android Studio 3.0, Gradle 3.0.0.

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
 More than one file was found with OS independent path 'project.properties'
```

I have tried the solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46431090/how-to-fix-more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-project-prope) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342455/more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-meta-inf-license), but with no success.
Also I tried downgrading gradle to version 2.3 but that didn't solve the problem either.

My build.gradle file :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aim.fjalortest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/project.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.0.0+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.12.0'
    //annotationProcessor 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.12.0'

    //jackson
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.5'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.5'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.5'

}
```

Can anyone help me figuring out what's causing this error?

Comment: replace `compile` with `implementation` , `androidTestCompile` with `androidTestImplementation` and `testCompile` with `testImplementation` and add `multiDexEnabled true` in `defaultConfig`

Comment: clean and Rebuild project. In my case it works fine.

Comment: @Ahishek no, it doesn't work

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Adding the following lines solved my problem:

```
packagingOptions {

        exclude 'project.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }
```

Comment: Is it a solution or a workaround? Why should we include these files?

Comment: I think it has to do with the libraries you add to the project. They can create additional .properties files on build so the system is confused which one to use. I am not sure about the details either.

Answer (score 7):

You can add this in yourProject/app/build.gradle inside android{}

```
packagingOptions {

    exclude 'project.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'

      exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
      exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
      exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
      exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
      exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
      exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
      exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
      exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding multidexEnabled to your app-level build.gradle,  as follows :

```
 defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
 }
```